Can I do conditional formatting based on a multiple choice (Drop-Down Menu) question? I want it to impact if the next questions shows up
Question 1 is a multiple choice drop-down question. Based on if certain answers are selected, I want following questions (Question2, Question3, ...) to show up. Is this possible in coding and how?
Question 1 Internal Name = Pleaseselectallthesustainability
Answer options for Question 1 are expertise 1, expertise 2, expertise 3
In Question 2, I tried the below formula but question 2 didn't show up if i did or didn't select 'expertise 1'.

